# Data class with more than 256 parameters, kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-class

I have data class as

```
data class GenericMessages(@SerializedName("title") @Expose
                       val title: String) : NavigationLocalizationMap(), Serializable
```

Package : `com.viewlift.models.data.appcms.ui.main`

I have more than 256 data members to be placed. Since 256 is maximum can be placed in constructor.

In another class I am using the class object I get the following error while building the project

```
/Users/wishy/Desktop/viewlift/appcms-tvod/AppCMS/src/main/java/com/viewlift/presenters/AppCMSPresenter.java:257: error: cannot access GenericMessages
import com.viewlift.models.data.appcms.ui.main.GenericMessages;
                                          ^
bad class file: /Users/wishy/Desktop/viewlift/appcms-tvod/AppCMS/buildout/tmp/kotlin-classes/mobileNonflavourDebug/com/viewlift/models/data/appcms/ui/main/GenericMessages.class
bad signature: ¾2
  ¤7
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

What is wrong over here?
How can I have more than 256 data members to data class?

Comment: is `GenericMessages` in separate module ?

Comment: `Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.` show your package declaration, also the folder structure

Comment: @ADM I have more than 256 members to pass in the constructor which is causing this issue

Comment: You are saying you have  256 properties of `GenericMessages` class constructor? Well i have never seen something like that .. I think you should consider using a `Builder` pattern . Or just minimize the properties by creating more data classes if possible

Comment: @ADM yes as these properties exist in API response and cannot be reduced. I am thinking of making use of map and should work fine

Comment: Map can be a better option for parsing without no hassle . Alternatively you can have the class with Builder pattern and write a custom de-serializer with GSON. [See this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer) i have never tried it but have look at this or similar topics . On the other hand I think u should minimize the response of API because u can not be using all 256 properties in a single screen (if its not a 3rd party API).